# How can I mock db connection in Spring Boot for testing purpose?

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-test

Situation:

1. I am using `Spring Cloud` with `Spring Boot` in a microservice, that microservice is loading a DB config information to configure a connection.
2. I created a test to get the rest interfaces using `Swagger` for documentation.
3. I want to disable the loading of DB configuration because is not necessary.

Here is the code:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class, Swagger2MarkupTest.class}, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")

public class Swagger2MarkupTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected Environment env;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void convertSwaggerToAsciiDoc() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/v2/api-docs").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(Swagger2MarkupResultHandler.outputDirectory("target/docs/asciidoc/generated")
                        .withExamples("target/docs/asciidoc/generated/exampless").build())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

How can I run the test without loading the database configuration?
Is this possible?

Comment: Mock your service layer. Simple as that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an option to fake Spring bean with just plain Spring features. You need to use `@Primary`, `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfiles` annotations for it.

[I wrote a blog post on the topic.](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/)

You can use in memory DB (e.g. H2) to replace real data source. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class TestingDataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .generateUniqueName(true)
            .setType(H2)
            .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
            .ignoreFailedDrops(true)
            .addScript("schema.sql")
            .addScripts("user_data.sql", "country_data.sql")
            .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: From the blog :     As of Spring Boot 1.4.0, faking of Spring Beans is supported natively via annotation @MockBean. Read [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) for more info.