# Mock database for Junit

Tags: oracle, junit, mocking

I use Oracle database with Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to get the query result.

Is there a way we can mock the connection and query result so that it can be used to write junits?

Also there is ping query which runs while making connection (select 1 from dual).How can we mock so that the connection doesn't fail because of ping query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707469/how-can-i-mock-db-connection-in-spring-boot-for-testing-purpose

Comment: It is possible but it would be terribly tedious to mocking all this stuff - you need to mock Connection, but also Statement, [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html), and probably aslo DatabaseMetadata and CallableStatement. It's almost like writing from scratch your own database driver :)  It's much easier just to instatiate an in memory database like H2, create few tables, fill them with some records and do the tests against this database.